# UML 2 state chart design for an LED and a CAN bus data logging sensor

Tags: architecture, embedded, uml, software-design, state-machine

I have the following requirement to design behaviors of **two software components**, one for writing data to SD card and another for controlling the LED based on the mode of SD card:

**Datalogging sensor** can write data to a FAT16-formatted SD card that is inserted into the card reader slot. When the board is booted and a valid card is detected, a new file is created and data from all messages on the can bus is written into this file. There is no mechanism to specifically close the log file. Just remove the card or power down the board.
There is a **bootloader** in the board which checks whether the SD card is valid or invalid and sends signal to datalogging sensor accordingly.

I have come up with the following state chart:
[image: logging sensor state machine]

To control the LEDs, there are two LEDs. I have following requirement:
**LED "LOGGER ON"**
When this LED is on, the SD card is present, has been detected and the file could be opened for writing.
**LED "LOGGER WRI"**
This LED blinks once each time a 512 Byte sector is dumped to the SD card.
The Write LED is turned on after the SD card has been initialized. If it stays on and the "LOGGER ON" LED stays off, the file system could not be initialized. Most likely this means that the SD card has the wrong format, but for some reasons even if the format is correct, filesystem initialization always fails on some cards.
I have come up with following state chart:
[image: led control]

Are my models correct?

Comment: It would seem to me that this should all be in your requirement specification. UML or state charts might be used to visualize the spec or determine what classes the program will have, but it shouldn't _be_ the specification. I'd expect some requirement about what to do upon file corruption, or how the LED(s) should blink, as some examples.

Comment: @Lundin I have specified a bit further on my own: **Bootloader** will send the signals (**SDCardValid and SDCardInvalid**) whether a sd card is valid or invalid. If **logging sensor** receives valid signal, **and there are error messages present**, sensor will write the data to sd card and notifies the **systemcontroller** that the sd card is in write mode via **SDCardWRI** signal. If sd card is **invalid**, logging sensor notifies the systemcontroller that there is problem with the sd card with **SDCardProblem** signal.

Comment: @Lundin There are 2 types of spec: the requirements from the customer to the supplier. And the detailed design going to the implementation (as well as confirmation to the customer). Giving just the requirements to the coders will loose hell.

Comment: @PriomBiswas SO is not meant for code review. Please come up with a specific question or try at another StackExchange (can't remember which were a better choice).

Comment: SE isn't very suitable for design questions overall. Software Engineering is completely unsuitable for any question, that site is broken beyond repair. So I don't think SE has any suitable site for this. I'd ask on software.codidact.com which is more tolerant for design and big picture issues.